# Lektor installation fails on Linux

Tags: pip, lektor

Lektor crashes on installation on Linux (Mint 19 and Raspbian-armv7l 2018-10) with a 'File not found error'

*Python 2.7 and 3.5 are installed.

    sudo apt-get install python-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev OK

    sudo apt-get install imagemagick OK*

```
curl -sf https://www.getlektor.com/install.sh | sudo sh
This script will install Lektor on your computer.
Installing at:
  bin: /usr/local/bin
  app: /usr/local/lib/lektor
Continue? [Yn] y -> CRASH !
/usr/bin/python: can't open file './virtualenv.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory  
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<stdin>", line 148, in <module>  
File "<stdin>", line 143, in main
File "<stdin>", line 107, in install
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
```

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Q: Did hacking `install.sh` resolve the problem for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with your version of Lektor:

> https://github.com/lektor/lektor/issues/619
>
> WORKAROUND:
>
> For my system, install.sh worked after changing line 124 to this:
>
> `Popen([sys.executable, './src/virtualenv.py', lib_dir], cwd=t).wait()`

Comment: Great.  Please "accept" the answer. So it won't remain "open", and so others who might experience the same problem can find the workaround.